# Asp.Net GridView Remove Html Styling

Tags: asp.net, gridview

When I'm using a grid view in Asp.Net, its auto-generated this ugly Html style : cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1"
style="border-collapse:collapse;

Is there a way to not have this styling at all ?

## UPDATE

Presently what I got is :

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_cphMain_gvTest" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
```

What I want :

```
<table id="ctl00_cphMain_gvTest">
```

So, no Html style at all. I want clean Html, I'll use CSS if I want to add style...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [CSS friendly ASP.NET 2.0 Control Adapaters](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/gridview.aspx) on the ASP.NET website.

It not only strips out most of the ugly attributes but also adds `thead` and `tbody` tags.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use skin file (themes) e.g.:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" BorderStyle="None" CellSpacing="5"/>
```

or you can write ControlAdapter in which you can control the whole rendering of GridView.

```
public class GridViewAdapter : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Adapters.WebControlAdapter
{
  protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {                
                GridView gridView = Control as GridView;
                if (gridView != null)
                {
                    writer.Indent++;
                    WritePagerSection(writer, PagerPosition.Top);

                    writer.WriteLine();
                    writer.WriteBeginTag("table");
                    writer.WriteAttribute("cellpadding", "0");
                    writer.WriteAttribute("cellspacing", "0");
                    writer.WriteAttribute("summary", Control.ToolTip);
...
```

then add adapter in browser file:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>    
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.GridViewAdapter" />
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Dears, to remove the automatic render of `cellpadding="0"`, that it is not Html5 compatible, I set the attribute `cellspacing` to -1 in the markup of GridView or set by code.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" CellSpacing="-1"/>
Me.GridView.cellspacing = -1
```

PS: I use .NET 4.5.

Comment: I was looking for a way to get rid of the `style="border-collapse:collapse;"` attribute, and `CellSpacing="-1"` did the trick. Bizarre default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Adding:

```
CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="None"
```

Will clean the markup considerably generating this in the web page:

```
<table border="0" id="GridView1">
```

There currently is no way to get rid of the final Border="0" but the above technique does clean up the table considerably.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.None;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10609319)

Comment: "This does not provide an answer to the question." did you read question in post ? and telling me this ?

Comment: I did yes. Does `GridLines.None` == `no Html style at all`?  And when I saw it, the answer had the word `bomb` in it and still there is no explaination as the *why* this answers the question.